# How to show Json string data in list view for multiple columns in Xamarin.android using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make an android app using Xamarin. As I am new to Xamarin, I am facing an issue i.e How to display JSON string data in to ListView or in to grid.

I am using WebApi to fetch data from database. Webapi returns string that is-

```
[{"QuestionId":2,"Question1":"4,8,12 Which Digit is Greatest?","Answer":"12"}]
```

Method I am using in android application is-

```
 private string QuestionList()
        {

            var url = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"url"));
            url.ContentType = "application/json";
            url.Method = "GET";
            string tempdata = string.Empty;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = url.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("error", response.StatusCode);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();


                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                    {

                        Console.Out.WriteLine("response");
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("response", content);
                        tempdata = content;
                    }
                }
            }
            return tempdata;
        }
```

It is returning Json string on my android device. Now I want to show this data in list or in a grid with multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use the Newtonsoft nuget package to convert this JSON string.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

You can use the website [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). Just provide the json string in the input and click in generate, it will be create the corresponding class for you.

After that you can use the xamarin documentation about list view in android.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/

This tutoriel will provide you some code examples to create a list view.

You will have to create a custom adapter if you want to "customize" your listview but it's quite easy to follow a tutorial about that.

To finish, I give you this last link :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZHLHrkvUt0

This is the link of a youtube channel with very good tutorials about android with xamarin. When I started using this technologie, I follow a lot of this videos.

If you need more help, don't hesitate to post a more advanced code.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Actually I want to display multiple rows, and i have gone through your help. but its not helping :(

Comment: Do you look the youtube channel ? that explain all the step to create a complexe list in android with xamarin